# Form a pyramid figure in Java using for loops

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to Java and I have to form this figure by using for loops:

```
    /:\
   /:::\
  /:::::\
 /:::::::\
/:::::::::\
```

Here is my code:

```
      for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++)
      {
         for (int column = 1; column <= row; column++)
         {
            System.out.print(" ");
         }
         for (int column = 1; column < row; column++)
         {
            System.out.print("/");
         }
         for (int column = 1; column < row; column++)
         {
            System.out.print(":");
         }
         for (int column = 1; column < row; column++)
         {
            System.out.print("\\");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
```

My code produces the following figure:

```
  /:\
   //::\\
    ///:::\\\
     ////::::\\\\
```

I'm not sure how to fix the spacing and reduce the amount of `for` loops in my code, any help/hints would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code ?

Comment: You should think about it as a grid so you basically need two for loops and not 5

Comment: What are your dimensions?

Comment: @Alex You double commented. What do you mean by dimensions?

Comment: > I have to form this figure by using for loops.

Is this for a class, if so then maybe i gave too much away haha

Comment: @Scratte Rows and Columns

Comment: That would be two dimensions, no? One dimension is rows and the other is columns. To me it looks like 5 rows. And whatever columns are necessary for the structure to be consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you see this:

```
  /:\
   //::\\
    ///:::\\\
     ////::::\\\\
```

To fix the spacing, change your first loop as such:

```java
for (int column = 1; column <= 5-row; column++)
{
  System.out.print(" ");
}
```

To get the right amount of colons, notice that we want a function that means the integers to the odd numbers, one function is f(n)=2n+1 and with 1-indexing, we can use f(n)=2n to fix that. You also have no need to print the sides in a loop.

Overall you should get something like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++)
      {
         for (int column = 1; column <= 5-row; column++)
         {
            System.out.print(" ");
         }
         System.out.print("/");
         for (int column = 1; column < 2*row; column++)
         {
            System.out.print(":");
         }
         System.out.print("\\");
         System.out.println();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things to consider.

- you only need one loop and that is for the rows.
- each row can be created with the `String.repeat()` method.  It's easier. Then you can transition to for loops.
- each row must be indented based on the current row.
- each row must have an odd number of colons, again based of the current row.

To control unnecessary newlines, use a combination of `System.print()` and `System.println()`

Just play around with it.  Remember that both `2*n-1` and `2*n+1` when `n` is an integer yields an odd number.

FYI

```
System.out.print(":".repeat(n));
```

is equivalent to

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.print(":");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be using `String::repeat` if you use Java 11 or later:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(" ".repeat((4 - i)) + "/" + ":".repeat(i * 2 + 1) + "\\");
}
```

For Java 8 it is possible to use `Collections::nCopies` and `String::join`:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%" + (5 - i) + "s%s\\%n", "/", String.join("", Collections.nCopies(2 * i + 1, ":")));
}
```